# Permissions for new GPO-controlled network share default to Read only on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server, access-denied, gpo, network-share

Came across a strange issue with lack of control over network share permissions on Windows Server - by a Windows Domain Controller-managed group policy.

*Goal*:

Create Read/Write network share on Windows Servers at remote branches via GPO.

*Attempted*:

1. Create new Group Policy object (GPO) with all in one package: 
   new **Folder**, **NTFS permissions** for the Folder and **Network Share** (located in the Computer Configuration section > Preferences > Windows Settings > Network Shares)
2. Link policy to Windows server and make sure it applies - new share is created remotely, successfully.

*Problem*:

Resulting network share is Read-Only for everyone (for the **Server version** of OS).
Users with Write-level access to the folder itself get Access Denied error, while accessing Network Share.

*Observations*:

There seems to be no way to configure permissions for the Network Share itself - using GPO. 
Apparently the default permissions for new network share are Read only - on Windows Server, but not (!) for client versions of Windows.

*Workaround*:

Create a script and deploy it to create network share locally.

What are your thoughts on this GPO deficiency?